# Incremental step value to jQuery Rangeslider Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, user-interface

[jQuery Mobile Rangeslider Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/) provides the `step` attribute to specify increment value.

Is there any way to customize this step value to increment like 0.1 upto 10 then 10 till 100 and so on

Widget value start from 0.1 , 0.2, 0.3,... until 1, then 2, 3,.. until 10, then 20, 30... until 100, then 200, 300... until 1000,...

Any hacks like this [one](http://www.elmundio.net/blog/jquery-mobile-vertical-slider/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest solution that I could found is [jQuery Simple Slider](http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/)